# writeMavenPom is not writing in pom

Tags: maven, pom.xml, jenkins-pipeline

According to https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/new-way-do-continuous-delivery-maven-and-jenkins-pipeline how should writing to a pom with pom.version.replace look like? I assume that pom.version.replace doesn't modify anything but how can the change be saved in pom?
I'm currently using this which fails with the update:

```
   def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
   def version = pom.version.replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")
   writeMavenPom model: pom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the pom object. The `replace` method will not modify the string but return a new one. Since you already stored the changed version you just need to overwrite the `pom.version`. The object returned by `readMavenPom` is a [Model](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html). This class has a `setVersion` method which can be used to change the version before writing the object with `writeMavenPom` to file.

So it should look like this:

```
def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
def version = pom.version.replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")
pom.version = version
writeMavenPom model: pom
```

Comment: Yes that was what I did

Answer (score 1):

Being inspired from a link I just pasted as a comment to another answer, you could as well have some look into new Maven features for continuous delivery. Namely, you can use properties now (starting with Maven 3.2.1) as a version:

```
<version>${releaseVersion}</version>
...
<properties>
  <releaseVersion>0-SNAPSHOT</releaseVersion> <!-- sane default -->
</properties>
```

So you could just pass your desired version during the build as a `-D`parameter:

```
mvn clean package -DreleaseVersion=1.2.3-45
```

See here for a detailed discussion: https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html

Comment: The problem arises when I need to change NPM project file too

Comment: @koller23 If your problem is more complex than editing a Maven POM, you should perhaps edit your question, or add a new one. Maven and NPM builds have technically nothing in common (although the workflow idea is quite similar).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [maven versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html).

Ypu can remove -SNAPSHOT with this command:

```
mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot
```

Comment: Ok, what to do if theres also NPM project file?

Comment: It's not a good practice to add SNAPSHOT tags in NPM so I assume that your pom.xml is not for a NPM project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add following instruction to save the data:

```
pom.version = pom.version.replace("-SNAPSHOT", "")
```

Although there are better options